# Apache httpclient: why doesn't retry when timeout

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

In apache httpclient 4.3, DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler's code

```
    if (exception instanceof InterruptedIOException) {
        // Timeout
        return false;
    }
```

It won't retry if it's timeout. What's the reason? Sometimes, the network is not stable, I just want to retry connection. I can use my own RetryHandler, but I just want to make sure if there is any problem if I retry when timeout.

Comment: Why aren't you using `catch (InterruptedIOException ...)`?

Comment: @Xilang I also want to retry in this case. Did you try overwriting the RetryHander to retry on InterruptedIOException? If so, how did it go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It won't retry if it's timeout. What's the reason?

Why should it? Timeouts usually defines a maximum period of inactivity between two consecutive operations. Why should the request be retried if it times out in the first place? If you are willing to wait longer for the operation to complete you should be using a greater timeout value.

Comment: I agree with your questions but a read or connect timeout defines the maximum time between initiating a read or connect and its failure, not the 'maximum period of inactivity betweeen two consecutive operations'.

Comment: Socket timeout is the maximum period of inactivity between two consecutive read operations (or how long the socket stays blocked in a read operation). Connect operation effectively consists of connection request from the connection manager and optional TCP connect

Comment: Thanks a lot! How do you think about this case:request has been sent, but the sever is stuck and not able to response, so I want to retry and sent another request.

Comment: HttpClient is likely to get get blocked waiting for a response until the socket timeout elapses and SocketTimeoutException is thrown. At this point it is entirely up to your application how to handle this condition.

Comment: In theory, yes, but in reality we constantly see timeouts occurring after waiting up to 2 minutes (the default). Meanwhile, requests attempted immediatley before or after connect with no problem. Shortening the timeout and adding a retry fixes the problem almost 100% of the time. I guess this is due to some edge case causing the timeout exception to occur sporadically, and it makes no difference how long the timeout is.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me. I tried to disable the retry option. The code below does the opposite.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler retryHandler = new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(0, true);
httpClient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(retryHandler);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used commercially a custom RetryHandler which mimics the Default* one, but allows retry for the following exceptions which we were getting regularly: ConnectTimeoutException and HttpHostConnectException. These exceptions were thrown a lot after a 15s timeout. The connection should be made sub-second so we now retry up to 3 times with 5s timeout, this has seen a large increase in successful connections being made on the second attempt.

We are still looking into why these connection requests aren’t being made in a timely manner between our azure app service and on-prem services.